# Unsubscribe from Angular's Location service

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription

I'm using Angular's (v5.2.2) Location service to track URL changes in a specific component.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location.subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === 'hashchange') {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to unsubscribe from the Location events when the component is destroyed.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.location.unsubscribe();
}
```

But I get the error:

```
this.location.unsubscribe is not a function
```

The problem is that the code continues to be executed when the URL is changed, even thought the page is different and this component is not even loaded.

How can I unsubscribe from the Location events?

Comment: Keep a reference to the subscription: `this.locationSubscription = this.location.subscribe(...);`

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I'll post the full code as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `subscribe` will return a reference to an object that allows future unsubscribe.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.locationSubscription = this.location.subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === 'hashchange') {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.locationSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use ISubscription interface from rx/js:
import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

2.Create a private variable as:

private subscription: ISubscription;

3.Subscribe to the observable returned:
this.subscription = this.location.subscribe(event => {

```
    if (event.type === 'hashchange') {
        this.doSomething();
    }
});
```

4.Unsubscribe easily:

ngOnDestroy() {

this.subscription.unsubscribe();

}