# Angular 6 - Back button press trigger more than once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code to detect the back button press using angular 6.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( private location: Location){
  this.handleBackButtonPress();
}
  handleBackButtonPress() {
    this.subscribed = true;
    this.location.subscribe(redirect => {
     if (redirect.pop === true) {
      alert('this is a backbutton click');
     }
    });
  }
}
```

This is working and we got alert on back button press. The problem is If we visit the same page more than once it will trigger the alert with the number of time we visited the route with the same component.

**Note**:
I have checked for a solution like `this.location.unsubscribe()`, But failed to find a function like that for `location`.

Comment: About unsubscribing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729990/unsubscribe-from-angulars-location-service . About the solution: you should **unsubscribe** when the event **onbeforeunload** of the browser is fired. Otherwise, `ngOnDestroy` won't be called, because it's not directly angular destroying the component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed by the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public subscription: SubscriptionLike;

  constructor(private location: Location){
    this.handleBackButtonPress();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleBackButtonPress() {
    this.subscription = this.location.subscribe(redirect => {
      if (redirect.pop === true) {
        alert('this is a backbutton click');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

*As mentioned by [briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275797/briosheje) in the comments the lifecycle hook does not run on browser refreshes. For that you'll need to handle the unsubscription on the document's `onbeforereload` event.*

Comment: Reasonable response, though **ngOnDestroy** won't be called upon a **refresh**. You should rather listen to the `onbeforeunload` event using `HostListener` and unsubscribe there instead, to me.

Comment: Beware of browser refreshes, though :P

Comment: @briosheje Very interesting. Did not know that subscriptions could persist browser reload for some browsers. I have included your contribution to my answer :)

Comment: @briosheje Thanks for remembering.Actually it was not in mind as a conern

Comment: @Daniel actually, the angular's **destroy** cycle is never called upon a refresh (which is misleading, since "destroy", from a semantical point of view, should be called whenever the component is effectively destroyed...). Usually this doesn't really impact any software at all, since most applications are built to actually work from whatever state the page is coming from... However, for that case specifically, it may impact a bit the overall cycle. Thanks for mentioning that above, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I analyzed here is, every time whenever constructor will run. It will call your function for sure. So you have to check whether this function has been run previously or not.
***Simplest answer is***

```
constructor( private location: Location){
 const PopCalled = localStorage.getItem('PopCalled')
 if(!PopCalled)
  this.handleBackButtonPress();
}

handleBackButtonPress() {
 this.subscribed = true;
  this.location.subscribe(redirect => {
  if (redirect.pop === true) {
  localStorage.setItem('PopCalled', true);
  alert('this is a backbutton click');
  }
 });
}
```

Basically, you have to manage the state of *PopCalled* its up to you which way you want to choose, as per my knowledge this is the simplest way.